# Access to one variable in multiple files in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.4

I have a package containing many `.py` files.

I want to:

1. have a debug flag, which I can access in each file. (Actually write it in one file, read it in all other files)
2. have a version number in each file, which is individual for each file. But I would like to create one function to get all version numbers of all files.

How do I define variables in these cases? How do I use `import`?

Edit:
I use an empty **__*init*__**.py file and:

## in package/classes.py:

debug = False

## in package/db.py:

from package.classes import *

print debug

Comment: Same way you'd import any thing else in Python.. functions are just variables in a module after all. Did you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)? (or use the [Python 2.4 version of the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/tut/tut.html)).

Comment: is the init file inside the package folder? in db you should type from classes import *, since you're already in the same module. see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a variable named `FLAG` in your `files/variables.py` file.

If the `files` folder has an empty `__init__.py` file inside, you just need to do

```
from files.variables import *
```

and you can access it in every file you import it.

To go with your example:

folder structure:

```
\program\ 
         \package\
                  __init__.py
                  classes.py
                  db.py
```

in db.py

```
from .classes import *
print debug
```

should work

About the versioning, if you want to do it manually i think you have to do the same, but it's a hassle to mantain by hand the versions.

Comment: I tried: 

# in package/classes.py:

debug = True

# in __init__.py:

from package.classes import *
from package/db import *

# in package/db.py:

print debug

What is wrong?

Comment: leave the init file empty, and eventually update the main post, not a comment, or it will be harder for us. the import statement should inside every file that's using it, not in the init actually

Comment: ".classes" does not work. and it does not know debug in the db.py if I use "package.classes" either. :( 
I just hate importing logics...

Comment: i see just now you're using python2.4, so maybe the '.classes' isn't working because of that. maybe there's something else lying around you're not telling us? like this, everything should work smoothly